# How to show this set is a Borel set?

Tags: measure-theory

How can I show that the set $\{  (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2|x>y , 0\le y\le \frac{1}{x} \}$ is a Borel set of the Borel algebra on $\Bbb R^2$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

You can write the set as intersection of an open set and a closed set.

Open and closed sets both belong to the [Borel-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set#Generating_the_Borel_algebra).