# How to show a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

How to show the following subset is a Borel set?
$$
\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y=x,0\leq x \leq 1\}.
$$

In [How to show this set is a Borel set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444919/how-to-show-this-set-is-a-borel-set), the answer is to write the set as intersection of an open set and a closed set.

I tried to do this. The problem is how to make sure $y=x$ when writting intersections and unions of open/close sets. It seems that I need uncountable union or intersection.

Comment: The set you gave is a line segment (of length $\sqrt{2})$ that contains both of its endpoints, and thus it is a closed set.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by sets $\prod\limits_{i=1}^2(-\infty,a_i];\ \ \ a_i\in \mathbb{R}$. Can we express ${(x,y)∈R2:y=x,0≤x≤1}$ by the sets that generate Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you want to use precisely the definition from your comment.

The proof may go as follows. First show that the closed rectangles are Borel. Use the quite obvious fact that the sets of the form $(a,b]\times (c,d]$ are Borel and approximate from above. Then consider the following sequence of coverings for your set:
$$A_n = \bigcup\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}[k/n,(k+1)/n)]\times[k/n,(k+1)/n].$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I desire.